# How To Use OOP concept for paasing values to database?

Tags: java, oop, jdbc

I have create a project for food ordering system. but my lecture said that you want to use Object Oriented Programming concept for this, So i want to know how i do it correctly using java classes.

here's my GUI code:

```
//get values from user
        int pId = Integer.parseInt(txtProductID.getText());
        String pName = txtPName.getText();
        String pCategory = combCategory.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Double price = Double.parseDouble(txtPrice.getText());
        Double qty = Double.parseDouble(combQty.getSelectedItem().toString());
        String description = txtDescription.getText();

        Product pr = new Product();

        if(pr.insertProduct(pId, pName, pCategory, price,qty,description)){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successly Added to DataBase!!");
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "UnsucessFully");

        }
```

Here's my Product Class

```
 //insert to product into database
   public static boolean insertProduct (int id,String name,String category,Double price,Double qty,String description){
          boolean flag = false;
        try {            
            DBconnector db = new DBconnector();
            con = db.connect();            
            String s="insert into product(id,name,category,price,qty,description) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(s);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, name);
                        preparedStatement.setString(3, category);
                        preparedStatement.setDouble(4, price);
                        preparedStatement.setDouble(5, qty);
                        preparedStatement.setString(6, description);

                        if(preparedStatement.executeUpdate()>0)
                            flag = true;

        }catch (SQLException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
       }

        return flag;
    }
```

So how i do this using OOP concept?

Comment: Create a `Product` class which carries the properties you are modeling, use this when interacting with your data layer (passing in and returning `Product`).  I might even consider having a `Product` manager class which does the basic operations which you need (add/insert, update, delete, query)

Comment: thanks a lot MadProgrammer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start:

```
    Product pr = new Product(pId, pName, pCategory, price, qty, description);

    if (pr.insert()) {
```

The `Product` class needs instance fields to represent the state of a product.  The `insert` method needs to be an instance method (not a `static` method) and it needs to write the state of the fields of `this`.

Since this is a teaching exercise, I'll leave you to do the rest.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen :)

Comment: Separate the database interaction from the Product state like MadProgrammer suggested.

Comment: Yea, maybe.  It depends on how sophisticated you need to be.  Handling the Product details as instance fields is probably what the teacher wants in the first instant though.